# I didn't know that you have to perform ghusl after period

Tags: salat, ghusl

So I just recently found out that you need to perform ghusl after period, I was so shocked because in our family I've never heard about ghusl before and my mom also didn't know it and we just do ablution after prayer. When I found out about it I told it to my mom and asked her to perform ghusl and she said she will ask her friend about (since she does not know how to perform ghusl and she didin't know that you have to do it after period)

I want to know If our prayer is accepted even if we did not perform ghusl?

Can anyone tell me how to do ghusl after period?

Btw I found out that you have to do ghusl during Ramadhan this year and I really want to know as how to perform it

I'm so sorry for my english and grammar please understand and please someone answer my question, Thank you so much

Comment: Note that how to do ghusl and whether your prayer is valid without ghusl are already two distinct questions, it is rather preferable to stick on one question per post. I'm not clear what you intend to say by: "*Btw I found out that you have to do ghusl during Ramadhan this year and I really want to know as how to perform it*" In order to be able to edit your posts you should consider registration on our site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intention matters. Our beloved Creator, The Most High ( All praise is due to him, The Most Benevolent, The Most Compassionate) knows what was in your heart and he knows the intent. Certainly The Oft-Forgiving, The Ever-Present, The Most Great will take everything into consideration. The circumstance has now become that you do know better now, and will be expected to follow the correct way that you learned. But do be sincere. Be sincere in your repentance for this and be sincere in your striving to do better. I hope this is helpful to you.

عَنْ أَنَسٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ ،  قَالَ : سَمِعْتُ  رَسُولَ اللهِ  صَلَّى الله عَلَيْهِ وَ سَلَّمَ ، يَقُولُ :

قَالَ اللهُ تَعَالَى : يَا ابْنَ ادَمَ ، إِنَّكَ مَا دَعَوْتََنِي  وَرَجَوْتَنِي ، غَفَرْتُ لَكَ عَلَى مَا كَانَ مِنْكَ وَلَا أُبالِي . يا  ابْنَ ادَمَ  :لَوْ بَلَغَتْ ذُنُوبُكَ عَنانَ السَّماءِ ثُم َّ  اسْتَغْفَرْتَني ، غَفَرْتُ لَكَ . يَا ابْنَ ادَمَ : إِنَّكَ لَوْ  أَتَيْتَنِي بِقُرَابِ الأَرْضِ خَطَايا ثُمَّ لَقِيتَني لَا تُشْرِكُ بِي  شَيْأً ، لَأَتيْتُكَ بِقُرَابِها مَغْفِرَةً

رواهُ الترمذي (وكذلك أحمد) وسنده حسن

On the authority of Anas (may Allah be pleased with him), who said:

I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: Allah the  Almighty said:

O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me and ask of Me, I shall  forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind. O son of Adam,  were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then to ask  forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you. O son of Adam, were you to come  to Me with sins nearly as great as the earth and were you then to face  Me, ascribing no partner to Me, I would bring you forgiveness nearly as  great as it.

It was related by at-Tirmidhi (also by Ahmad ibn Hanbal). Its chain of  authorities is sound.

40 Hadith Qudsi
(40 Hadith Qudsi)
Arabic/English book reference : Hadith 34

عَنْ  ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ عَنْهُمَا، عَنْ النَّبِيِّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ  عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ، فِيمَا يَرْوِي عَنْ رَبِّهِ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ، قَالَ:
"إِنَّ اللَّهَ كَتَبَ  الْحَسَنَاتِ وَالسَّيِّئَاتِ، ثُمَّ بَيَّنَ ذَلِكَ: فَمَنْ هَمَّ  بِحَسَنَةٍ فَلَمْ يَعْمَلْهَا، كَتَبَهَا اللَّهُ لَهُ عِنْدَهُ حَسَنَةً  كَامِلَةً، فَإِنْ هُوَ هَمَّ بِهَا فَعَمِلَهَا، كَتَبَهَا اللَّهُ لَهُ  عِنْدَهُ عَشْرَ حَسَنَاتٍ، إِلَى سَبْعِمِائَةِ ضِعْفٍ، إِلَى أَضْعَافٍ  كَثِيرَةٍ، وَمَنْ هَمَّ بِسَيِّئَةٍ فَلَمْ يَعْمَلْهَا، كَتَبَهَا  اللَّهُ لَهُ عِنْدَهُ حَسَنَةً كَامِلَةً، فَإِنْ هُوَ هَمَّ بِهَا  فَعَمِلَهَا، كَتَبَهَا اللَّهُ سَيِّئَةً وَاحِدَةً"
.
رواه البخاري ومسلم

On  the authority of son of Abbas (may Allah be pleased with them both),  from the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), among the sayings he related from his  Lord (glorified and exalted be He) is that He said:

Allah has written down the good deeds and the bad ones. Then He  explained it [by saying that] he who has intended a good deed and has  not done it, Allah writes it down with Himself as a full good deed, but  if he has intended it and has done it, Allah writes it down with Himself  as from ten good deeds to seven hundred times, or many times over. But  if he has intended a bad deed and has not done it, Allah writes it down  with Himself as a full good deed, but if he has intended it and has done  it, Allah writes it down as one bad deed.

It was related by al-Bukhari and Muslim.

40 Hadith Qudsi
(40 Hadith Qudsi)
Arabic/English book reference : Hadith 16

عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ قَالَ: قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ:
" لَمَّا قَضَى اللَّهُ  الْخَلْقَ، كَتَبَ فِي كِتَابِهِ عَلَى نَفْسِهِ، فَهُوَ مَوْضُوعٌ  عِنْدَهُ: إِنَّ رَحْمَتِي تَغْلِبُ غَضَبِي"

رواه مسلم (وكذلك البخاري والنسائي وابن ماجه)
On the authority of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him), who said that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

When Allah decreed the Creation He pledged Himself by writing in His  book which is laid down with Him: My mercy prevails over my wrath.  It was related by Muslim (also by al-Bukhari, an-Nasa'i and Ibn Majah).

40 Hadith Qudsi
(40 Hadith Qudsi)
Arabic/English book reference : Hadith 1

عَنْ أَبي هُرَيْرَةَ ،  رَضِيَ  اللهُ عَنْهُ ،  عَنِ النَّبَيِّ  صَلَّى الله عَلَيْهِ وَ سَلَّمَ ، فِيما  يَحْكِي عَنْ رَبِّهِ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ ، قَالَ    :

أَذْنَبَ عَبْدٌ ذَنْبًا ، فَقَالَ : اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبي .  فَقَالَ تَبَارَكَ وَتَعَالى : أَذْنَبَ عَبْدِي ذَنْبًا ، فَعَلِمَ أنَّ  لَهُ رَبّاً ، يَغْفِرُ الذَّنْبَ ، وَيَأْخُذُ بِهِ . ثُمَّ عَادَ  فَأَذْنَبَ ، فَقَالَ : أَيّ رَبِّ ، اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِِي ، فَقَالَ  تَبَارَكَ وتَعَالى : عَبْدِي أَذْنَبَ ذَنْباً . فَعَلِمَ أَنَّ لَهُ  رَبّاً يَغْفِرُ الذَّنْبَ ، ويَأْخُذُ بِهِ . ثُمَّ عَادَ فَأَذْنَبَ ،  فَقَالَ : أَيّ رَبِّ ، اغْفِرْ لِي ذَنْبِي : فَقَالَ تَبَارَكَ  وَتَعَالَى : أَذْنَبَ عَبْدِي ذَنْباً ، فَعَلِمَ أَنَّ لَهُ رَبّاً ،  يَغْفِرُ الذَّنْبَ ، ويَأْخُذُ بالذَّنْبِ . اعْمَلْ مَا شِئْتَ ، فَقَدْ  غَفَرْتُ لَكَ .

رواهُ مسلم (وكذلك البخاري)

On  the authority of Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the  Prophet (ﷺ), from among the things he reports from his Lord (mighty and  sublime be He), is that he said:

A servant [of Allah's] committed a sin and said: O Allah, forgive me my  sin. And He (glorified and exalted be He) said: My servant has committed  a sin and has known that he has a Lord who forgives sins and punishes  for them.
Then he sinned again and said: O Lord, forgive me my sin. And  He (glorified and exalted be He) said: My servant has committed a sin  and has known that he has a Lord who forgives sins and punishes for  them.
Then he sinned again and said: O Lord, forgive me my sin. And He  (glorified and exalted be He) said: My servant has committed a sin and  has known that he has a Lord who forgives sins and punishes for sins. Do  what you wish, for I have forgiven you
.
It was related by Muslim (also by al-Bukhari).

40 Hadith Qudsi
(40 Hadith Qudsi)
Arabic/English book reference : Hadith 33

عَنْ جُنْدُبٍ رَضِيَ اللهُ عَنْهُ : أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللهِ  صَلَّى الله عَلَيْهِ وَ سَلَّمَ حَدَّثَ

(أَنْ رجُلاً قال : واللهِ لا يَغْفِرُ اللهُ لِفُلانٍ وإِنَّ اللهَ  تَعَالَى قَالَ : مَنْ ذَا الَّذِي يَتَأَلَّى عَلَيَّ أَنْ لا أَغْفِرَ  لِفُلان،فَإِنِّي قَدْ غَفَرْتُ لِفُلانٍ، وأَحْبَطْتُ عَمَلَكَ (أَوْ  كَمَا قَال
رواه مسلم

On the authority of Jundub (may Allah be pleased with him), who said that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) related:

A man said: By Allah, Allah will not forgive So-and-so. At this Allah  the Almighty said: Who is he who swears by Me that I will not forgive  So-and-so? Verily I have forgiven So-and-so and have nullified your [own  good] deeds (1) (or as he said [it]).
(1) A similar Hadith, which is given by Abu Dawud, indicates that the  person referred to was a goldly man whose previous good deeds were  brought to nought through presuming to declare that Allah would not  forgive someone's bad deeds.

It was related by Muslim.

40 Hadith Qudsi
(40 Hadith Qudsi)
Arabic/English book reference : Hadith 31

Comment: This almost misses the topic of the question entirely. OP needs answers on how to perform ghusl, and whether her prayers are accepted without it not a bundle of references! Answers here should be well elaborated in your own words, focused on answering the question asked (entirely) and any claims being supported by evidences. See [answer].

Comment: Apologies. I was trying to answer part of the question. I understand.